# How to make git reset previous credentials on OS X?

Tags: macos, git, github, credentials

I'm a Git instructor, so must have multiple GitHub accounts for demonstration purposes. I'm using Git on both Ubuntu, Windows and sometimes in OS X.

[image]

I have a problem in OS X where Git remembers the previous credentials. According to the screen shot, I want to push a testing repository to GitHub account of jeud, but Git remembers the credentials of account tutor4dev, so Git never prompts me for any authentication like I would get when using Ubuntu and Windows.

I have tried `git config credential.https://github.com.jeud jeud`, but it's still not working.

Please guide what to do, thanks.

***Edited***

In my case, I can reset the current username and password using */Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access*

But if possible, I would like Git to prompt me for authentication every time when github.com requires for credential.

I have removed the credential helper using `git config --global --unset credential.helper` and setup core.askpass using `git config --global core.askpass true`, but Git still uses the username and password stored in the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my problem by deleting existing credential on my machine using */Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access*

Comment: Could you please clarify? You have deleted that file or you 'used' that file to delete your credentials? On my OSX, I have /Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app, not sure if it's the same thing

Comment: open Keychain app and delete github.com from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
git config --global --edit
```

That should show you the contents of `.gitconfig` located at:

```
~/.gitconfig
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm pretty sure there is no credential stored in the .gitconfig

Comment: You're pretty sure, or 100% positive? I'm certain (**without any shred of doubt**) that credentials are in mine.

Comment: I didn't mean to argue, user.email is not credential, it's just information to be stored as who is making the commits. One thing as common sense the credential should be **a pair of username and password** and the credential will never be stored in unsecured storage like the no password protected text file.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, however, the term credentials does not specifically regard the meaning as you've said. In OSX any private information, or security certificates would be stored within keychain (generally). The reason I suggested you check the .gitconfig was for the possibility that it might be checking there for the basic user info, then moving onto the authentication portion you're referring to. I'm not here to argue either, just suggesting that the configuration has to start somewhere to know which secure key to use.